# Symfony2 Form Events without entity

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine, formbuilder

I want to make a search form that acts independently from the entity, so there's no entity,  and a choice field is dynamically loaded from other using FormEvents but no matter what always getting $formE->getData() NULL

this is my code of the controller

```
   public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('Numero', TextType::class,array('required' => false,))
        ->add('FechaIngresoRango',TextType::class,array('required' =>            false,))
      ->add('Criterio', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices'  => array(
                        '' => '-Seleccione Opcion-',
                        'form_Numero' => 'NUMERO',
                        'form_Sector' => 'AREA',
                        'inputGroupsTema' => 'TEMA',
                        'form_FechaIngresoRango' => 'FECHA INGRESO',
            ),'required' => true))

        ->add('Sector','entity', array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Sector',
                'property' => 'nombre',
                'required' => false
        ))
        ->add('Tema','entity', array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\TipoTemaExpediente',
                'property' => 'tipoTemaExpediente',
                'required' => false
        ))->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $formE = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();
            var_dump($data);
            {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $tiposSubTema = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:TipoSubTemaExpediente')->findAll();

            //$tipoTema = $data->getTipoTemaExpediente();
            $formE->add('tipoSubTemaExpediente',EntityType::class,array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:TipoSubTemaExpediente',
                'property' => 'subTemaExpediente',
                'choices' => $tiposSubTema,
            )); 
            }
            //else
            {
                //$formE->add('tipoSubTemaExpediente',ChoiceType::class, array('attr' => array('disabled' => true),));
            }
        })
        ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $data = $form->getData();
//          switch ($data['Criterio']){
//              case "form_Numero" : 
//                  var_dump($data['Numero']);
//                  break;
//              case "form_Sector" :
//                  var_dump($data['Sector']->getId());
//                  break;
//              case "inputGroupsTema" :
//                  var_dump($data['Tema']->getTipoTemaExpediente());
//                  break;
//              case "form_FechaIngresoRango" :
//                  var_dump($data['FechaIngresoRango']);
//                  break;
//          }

        }
```

the comments are from several test that I did, on post works flawlessly the problem is the event, I'm starting to think that if no entity is related on the form creation there's no way that this going to work, is that so?

Comment: Bit of a shot in the dark but you might try passing an an array with keys like Numero and Sector for the initial data.

Comment: Yes, i took the cowards exit, i did fill the combos at start and the filter by jquery, Thanks